# Excel ADODB Sql Query Execution taking hours when manipulate excel tables

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba, ado

I have 28000 records with 8 column in an sheet. When I convert the sheet into ADODB database and copy to new excel using below code it is executing in less than a min

```
Set Tables_conn_obj = New ADODB.Connection
    Tables_conn_str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Table_Filename & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR = Yes;IMEX=1"""
    Tables_conn_obj.Open Tables_conn_str
    First_Temp_sqlqry = "Select * INTO [Excel 12.0;DATABASE=C:\Prod Validation\Database\Second Acat Table.xlsb].[Sheet1]  Table [first - Table$];"
    Tables_conn_obj.Execute First_Temp_sqlqry
```

But when I change the query to manipulate one column in current table based on another table in the same excel and try to copy the results in another excel, it is taking more than one hour.. **why it is taking this much time when both the query results returns the same number of rows and column?**

Even I tried `copyfromrecordset`, `getrows()`, `getstring()`, Looping each `recordset` fields options all of them taking same amount of time. Is there any excel expert who can help me in this issue.  Appreciate any inputs...

**Important note: Without into statement even below query is executing in few seconds.**

**Manipulating first column based on other table data**

```
select (
iif( [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]    =   (select max([ACAT$].[new_Agent_number]) from  [ACAT$]        where [ACAT$].[new_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]    and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] = ( select MAX([ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] ) from  [ACAT$]     where [ACAT$].[new_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] > '2014-10-01') )   , (select max([ACAT$].[Old_Agent_number]) from  [ACAT$]     where [ACAT$].[new_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]  and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] = ( select MAX([ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] )  from  [ACAT$]     where [ACAT$].[new_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] > '2014-10-01')) ,

iif(   [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]    =  (select max([ACAT$].[Old_Agent_number]) from  [ACAT$]    where [ACAT$].[Old_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]    and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] = ( select MAX([ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] ) from  [ACAT$]where [ACA
T$].[Old_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] <= '2014-10-01') ), (select max([ACAT$].[new_Agent_number]) from  [ACAT$]     where [ACAT$].[Old_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent] and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] = ( select MAX([ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] )  from  [ACAT$]    where [ACAT$].[Old_Agent_number] = [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent]and [ACAT$].[ACAT_EffectiveDate] <= '2014-10-01')) ,

[Second - Table$].[Policy Agent] ))) as [Policy Agent],
```

**Summing up all other columns**

```
(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Auto BW-Line Of Business Detail])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Auto BW-Line Of Business Detail]))) as [Auto BW-Line Of Business Detail],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Auto Farmers])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Auto Farmers]))) as [Auto Farmers],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[MCA])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[MCA]))) as [MCA],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[CEA])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[CEA]))) as [CEA],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Commercial P&C])),0,sum([Second - 
Table$].[Commercial P&C]))) as [Commercial P&C],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Comm WC])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Comm WC]))) as [Comm WC],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Fire Farmers])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Fire Farmers]))) as [Fire Farmers],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Flood])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Flood]))) as [Flood],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Kraft Lake])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Kraft Lake]))) as [Kraft Lake],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Life])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Life]))) as [Life],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Foremost])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Foremost]))) as [Foremost],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[Umbrella])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[Umbrella]))) as [Umbrella],(iif(isnull(sum([Second - Table$].[MCNA])),0,sum([Second - Table$].[MCNA]))) as [MCNA] 

INTO [Excel 12.0;DATABASE=C:\Prod Validation\Database\Second Acat Table.xlsb].[Sheet1] 

from [Second - Table$] group by [Second - Table$].[Policy Agent] ;
```

Comment: Welcome,please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I am new to this forum.. Thanks for guiding this

Comment: Probably not the _main_ culprit, but be aware that the `IIf()` statement will evaluate both true _and_ false parts regardless of the test condition being met. You're better going with an If/Then/Else structure for this kind if thing as you're currently executing all conditional code regardless...

Comment: Thanks for the input, But I just executed the same query without into statement it ran in seconds. But to process the result recordset again it is taking hours... Dont no why ??

Answer (score 0):

Dividin the queries into three steps and udating the same tables to get the final results using the option `Provider=MSDASQL` instead of `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in connection string works perfectly for me.